# Error while fetching Record values in Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, formula, controller, custom-controller

I have a requirement to get all sponsor ids from Process record and store it on User record as multi-select picklist values.

below is my logic:

```
list<user> user = [SELECT ID from User where name = 'Test User']; 
List <Process__c> Processlist = [
  SELECT ID,Sponsor__c 
  FROM Process__c 
  Where User_Name__c = :user];

  
List<string> allProsList = new list<string>();
for (Process__c Process : Processlist) {
  allProsList.add(Process.Sponsor__c);
}
for(User us : user){
    us.Sponsor_Ids__c = String.join(allProsList,';');
}
```

Now, using this logic, I am getting duplicate Sponsor values.
Suppose, if there are 100 Process records with same Sponsor Ids, i am seeing 100 Sponsor IDs on User record.

Is there anyway that i can get unique Sponsor id from Process object and store it in User record.
Here, **Process is child and Sponsor is Parent**

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Set <String>` in place of `List<String>`. Using a set will remove all duplicate instances of the Sponsor Id (Sponsor__c)

```
Set<string> allProsList = new Set<string>(); //List<string> allProsList = new list<string>();
for (Process__c Process : Processlist) {
  allProsList.add(Process.Sponsor__c);
}
```

allProsList will contain distinct set of Sponsor__c values.

Hope this helps.

```
//Pseudo code to bulkify the code - 
listProcess = [SELECT Id,User_Name__c FROM Process__c WHERE <Add Filter conditions other than "User_Name__c =" as we will query the users in the next step>];
Set<Id> userId;
for(Process p : listProcess){
userId.add(p.User_Name__c); //This is the set of user Ids related to the Process records
}
```

//This is the list of Users related to the Process Records.
userList = [SELECT Id FROM User Where Id IN: userId];
// Update Sponsor Ids on this list.

Comment: Do note that `String.join()` still requires a List. Thankfully, it's easy to convert a Set to a List as List has a constructor that takes a Set, `new List<String>(mySet)`

Comment: Thanks @Shashank..
Is there anyway I can query only those users which are present Process object instead of fetching and updating all of them?

Comment: @SFDCUser It depends how are you invoking the process. Is it a trigger on Process object? You need to provide more details regarding your problem.

Comment: I am performing the update operation from Anonymous window as this is a one time process